# Encountering a Run-Time error while running this python script for importing a Speech to Text Model

Tags: python, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

```
import nemo
import ffmpeg
import nemo.collections.asr as nemo_asr
model = nemo_asr.models.EncDecCTCModel.from_pretrained(model_name="QuartzNet15x5Base-En")
files=["D:\archive\medical speech transcription and intent\Medical Speech, Transcription, and Intent\recordings\test\1249120_1853182_11719913.wav"]
transcription=model.transcribe(paths2audio_files=files)
```

I am getting a Warning and a runtime error

Warning: warn("Couldn't find ffmpeg or avconv - defaulting to ffmpeg, but may not work", RuntimeWarning)

Runtime Error:
An attempt has been made to start a new process before the
current process has finished its bootstrapping phase.

```
    This probably means that you are not using fork to start your
    child processes and you have forgotten to use the proper idiom
    in the main module:

        if __name__ == '__main__':
            freeze_support()
            ...

    The "freeze_support()" line can be omitted if the program
    is not going to be frozen to produce an executable.
```

Any help on how to proceed would be appreciated!